# Elasticsearch phrase_prefix query with english analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm doing a basic [`phase_prefix` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) and noticed strange results when searching for a document with a `text` field containing the word "alyssum". Here are the results for the given search terms:

- `"al"` - hit
- `"aly"` - miss
- `"alys"` - miss
- `"alyss"` - hit

These 4 scenarios were also tested with multi-word search phrases that *end* with the prefixes above, which yielded the same results. After a little experimenting, the culprit turned out to be the analyzer set in the index settings:

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "default": {
      "type": "english"
    }
  }
```

Without specifying the `english` language analyzer, I get hits in all 4 scenarios. Although I'm not completely wrapping my head around why the second and third scenarios did not produce hits as expected, I imagine it has to do with stemming and the fact that "s" and "ly" are meaningful English suffixes.

At the application level, the `english` analyzer works great in the vast majority of scenarios. Even for `phrase_prefix` queries (relatively few) we would ideally like to apply its rules to all but the last word in the search phrase (i.e. the prefix). Is there a way to maintain `english` analyzer rules in general yet somehow get hits in all 4 scenarios above?